# TYPO3: Changing the order of displayed tables in the list module

Tags: typo3, backend

Is it possible to change the order of the displayed (database) tables in the backend list module? I've got a sysfolder with several different tables of my extension and i want the "important" tables to be shown on top. TYPO3 Version is 6.2 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since TYPO3 7 you can do that with page TSconfig:

```
mod.web_list.tableDisplayOrder
```

See also:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/PageTsconfig/Mod.html#tabledisplayorder

Answer (score 0):

The tables are displayed in the same order as TCA arrays are ordered in `ext_tables.php` in your extension.

Don't forget to `Flush system cache` (now in Install Tool > Important actions) to reflect the changes.

**EDIT: Important for extensions built with Builder 6.2:**

To make sure that works you need to replace `$GLOBALS['TCA']` to `$TCA` in `ext_tables` and all TCA files!

For an example change every occurrence of:
`$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_mymodel']`
to
`$TCA['tx_myext_domain_model_mymodel']`

Clear the system cache from Install Tool and it will work.

Comment: But how to change the order without having to rename the models?

    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_Cmodel'] = array(...)  
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_Bmodel'] = array(...)  
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_Amodel'] = array(...)  

I want "Cmodel" to be on top in list module (it is the first item in ext_tables.php), but the tables are ordered alphabetically...

Comment: I think i'm to stupid: The first 3 lines are `addLLrefForTCAdescr` and `allowTableOnStandardPages` and `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_domain_model_onTopModel'] = array(...)`, the rest comes from `Configuration/TCA/onTopModel.php`. I cannot move this lines more to top... Can i show you my ext_tables.php and how to do so?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7PhBG3YZ - `tx_birealestate_domain_model_property` i want to be shown on top!

Comment: Just compared with other installation, and found similar problem you have, solution is simple, check my edit.

Comment: Great! I will try this tomorrow. Does the switch from $GLOBALS['TCA'] to $TCA have any side effects? Or is $TCA the new "6.2-way-to-do" in general?

Comment: as I can see `$TCA` is filled with `$GLOBALS['TCA']` at the init, so much faster before TYPO3 renders i.e. List module tables, so _I think_ there's no any disadventage in your TCA definition files. As can see also extbase sysext uses it.